# Alchemist starting formulas

Tags: pathfinder-1e, alchemist

> An alchemist begins play with two 1st level formulae of his choice,
>   plus a number of additional forumlae equal to his Intelligence
>   modifier.

Just want to make sure I'm getting this right. I have bonus extracts/formulas I can prepare each day due to my int, so that means I can prepare a level 2 extract, if I know a 2nd level formula to make. The section above says I get to learn two first level formulas, but then for the extras I get from my int modifier, those have to be level 1 as well, not just any level formula that I can make, right? I can't use the extra four from my int mod to learn second level formulas. That's how I'm taking it, not wanting to take something I shouldn't, but I figured I may as well make sure.

EDIT:Using Pathfinder

Answer (score 8):

- If a level 1 [alchemist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist/) has Int 11, he can create 1 1st-level Extract Per Day.
- If a level 1 alchemist has Int 12-19, he can create 2 1st-level Extracts Per Day.
- If a level 1 alchemist has Int 20-29, he can create 3 1st-level Extracts Per Day.

But, barring other influences (e.g. archetypes, feats, magic items, special abilities, traits), *that's all he can create.* He *can't* create 2nd-level or higher extracts, and he *can't* use the higher-level bonus Extracts Per Day to create lower-level extracts.

Although a high Intelligence score lets an alchemist create more higher-level Extracts Per Day, an alchemist *can't* create additional higher-level Extracts Per Day those until he has a *number* instead of a dash of Extracts Per Day of that extract level according to [Table: Alchemist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist).

So while a high Intelligence remains extremely valuable for an alchemist, that high Intelligence doesn't let him create Extracts Per Day of an extract  level *beyond* what his alchemist class level dictates he can create.

The alchemist's Extracts Per Day follow the same rules as [Bonus Spells Per Day](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/ability-scores#TOC-Abilities-and-Spellcasters) for spellcasters.

#### What would happen if an alchemist *could*

I'm mainly guessing, but I think you were thinking that because of an Intelligence score of 18, a 1st-level alchemist would be able to create 1 additional 1st-level, 2nd-level, 3rd-level, and 4th-level Extracts Per Day *if* he could gain access to those formulae. The game expects, however, according to Table: Alchemist, a *10th-level* alchemist to be able to create 1 4th-level Extract Per Day. In other words, an ability most characters would wait to use until halfway through their careers (i.e. creating 4th-level extracts) would be available to a 1st-level alchemist with Intelligence 18.

The game doesn't expect a level 1 alchemist to use 4th-level extracts like *[freedom of movement](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/freedom-of-movement)* and *[greater invisibility](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/i/invisibility)* even *once* per day, and you'd likely find such a character overcoming challenges far beyond his expected abilities, leading to DM frustration at the DM's inability to challenge such a character without killing him outright and, perhaps, boredom (or terror!) while playing a character who can casually overcome challenges far beyond his ability in an extremely limited manner. You *can* play that way, but you should be aware you're choosing to change the rules, and your experiences with the game will be *vastly* different than those who are otherwise playing the same game.

#### A minor rules quirk

The supernatural ability [alchemy](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist/#TOC-Alchemy-Su-) says, "An alchemist begins play with two 1st level formulae of his choice, plus a number of additional forumlae equal to his Intelligence modifier." That last part means that an alchemist always begins play with 2 1st-level formulae but that his Intelligence modifier lets him select additional formulae of *any* level. He can't *use* those higher-than-1st-level formulae when he's a level 1 alchemist, but he could totally have in his formula book as many 2nd-level-through-6th-level formulae as his Intelligence modifier allows.

Again, the level 1 alchemist *can't* yet create extracts with such formulae, but he could—if he encounters appropriate folks during the campaign—*trade* that formula knowledge for other goods or services from a higher-level alchemist that desires such formula knowledge. Of course, such a higher-level alchemist may, instead, opt to simply *disappear* the low-level alchemist and abscond with his formula book, but a low-level alchemist choosing to have high-level formulae in his formula book *is* an option, albeit an unusual and potentially dangerous one.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Nice to know that last part, as I'm not sure there are as many 1st level formulas I want as I can get. Even though I can't use them yet, taking some extra higher level ones for when I can use them could also be useful. Like the other ways you've come up with to make use of them as well.

Comment: @playerzero make sure to click the check mark near the top left of this post to mark it as answered