# Additional spells/day at First Level

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Can a level 1 Oracle use the additional spell slots gained by having a high Charisma to cast the low level spells she knows or are those slots initially wasted?  Can spell slots generally be used to cast a lower spell than their level?

Comment: [Related](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/31814/8610)... I think. That is, *if* you mean the additional 2nd, 3rd, and so on level spell slots.

Comment: This is effectively two questions, both of which have been asked and answered on this site. [Can a spellcaster use spell slots above their normal limit if their ability scores allow bonus spells of that level?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/36325/4563) and [Lower spells in higher spell slots](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/3510/4563). If the answers to these *don’t* answer your question, please edit your question to explain what is still confusing you. Until then, this question will be put On Hold. If your question *is* answered, feel free to leave it On Hold, and to ask any other questions.